# Expand all entries in tree with one click

Tags: android-studio

Everytime reopen my android studio project all entries of the left tree get closed.
How to avoid that / or open them with one click instead of open one by one?

**Directly show:**

[image]

**Instead of:**

[image]

Comment: Interesting usage pattern. I don't think it's possible, but I might be proven wrong. Note also, that you haven't "auto-opened" _all_ entries in your example, the `strings.xml` entry for example is still collapsed. Can I ask why you need this particular behaviour? Using "autoscroll to/from source" might alleviate your navigation problems somewhat. Maybe.

Comment: Hmm I working on all files parallel and don't want to expand every folder manually..
Yeah I didn't opend `strings.xml` because I forgot it.. It's easier for me to stay on top of all my files ;) You don't have to understand that.

Comment: Oh, I just realised, my Android Studio doesn't show this behaviour. Closing and re-opening a project does _not_ auto collapse items in the Android tab. I'm using version 1.2.1.1

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 1.3. It's not every time, yes..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open the selected file and Use "Scroll from Source" to directly navigate to the required file

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah that helped me a lot! :) Didn't clicked that because I had to recreate my project now for over 5 times.. Thank you

Answer (score 13):

Another way to expand entire directory structure is to click/select any folder from where you want to expand the sub directories and **click-hold right arrow button**, this will do the job.

Comment: I wish this could happen instantly though

Answer (score 8):

You can click on the item you want to expand and press number pad's * button. This will expand all the folders in that level of the tree. Any sub folders will need to be expanded though. Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27334895/4253378).

Comment: Please don't post [identical answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45699707) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Answer (score 6):

Best way is to go to Android Studio Preferences and search for `Fully Expand Tree Node`. There you can either add abbreviation specific to you or new shortcut. Usually you select package you want to expand and search with double pressing `Shift` then you hit it or use that shortcut and every sub directory or package will get expanded. There is no delay its instant.