# How to show all files in Intellij IDEA project view?

Tags: intellij-idea

In new version 2017.3 they added this feature and I can't find menu to turn it off.

[image]

Comment: I found solution, this was .ignore plugin feature, so when I uninstalled this plugin, it had fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the post's title, I assume you are asking for a menu entry to fully collapse a partially or fully expanded project in Intellij Idea (i.e. "How to un-show all files...", not "How to show all files...").

I don't know of any menu entry to do that. However, you can just hold down the left arrow key to completely collapse the entire project as long as you have any node in your project selected (per my comment to this SO post: [Intellij, project navigation. Expand all folder and file tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334649/intellij-project-navigation-expand-all-folder-and-file-tree)).

If you just tap the left arrow key instead of holding it down it will collapse the structure for the currently selected node.

For the key mapping see **File -> Settings... -> Keymap -> Editor Actions -> Left**.